# Entity Framework check result null

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am using this query:

```
 var result = from r in db.Registrations
              join u in db.UserTypes on r.UserTypeId equals u.UserTypeId
              where r.Email.ToLower()==model.LoginEmail.ToLower() && r.Password.ToLower() == model.Password.ToLower()
              select new { r,u};
```

Here how can I check that if no record is found? If so, then

```
 if(result == null)
     // no record found
 else
     // record found
```

Comment: Just a note, I can't help but notice that your password handling seems quite bad. First you seem to do a clear text comparison - that's extremely bad practice, please look into Salting and Hashing. Then you even do `.ToLower()` which means you take away half the options that users have to make their passwords hard-to-guess which is the *whole point of passwords anyway*.

Comment: @PeterB thansk for suggestion, I have updated my code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First what you assign to a result is just IQueryable so it's query and you need to execute it first. So I suggest renaming it to query and then do it like this:

```
var query= from r in db.Registrations
           join u in db.UserTypes on r.UserTypeId equals u.UserTypeId
           where r.Email.ToLower()==model.LoginEmail.ToLower() && r.Password.ToLower() == model.Password.ToLower();    
           select new { r,u};

var result = query.FirstOrDefault(); // gives first result or null
if (result == null) {
  // no record
} else {
  // record found and is in result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Any` or `Count` extension method:

```
 if(!result.Any())
///norecord found
else
//record found
```

Using `Count` would be:

```
 if(result.Count()==0)
///norecord found
else
//record found
```

Comment: And `.Any()` would be strongly preferred, because typically you really don't need to know that your list contains 178'964 entries (and counting those might take quite a bit of time!) -- you're really just interested in the fact **IF** the list contains **at least one** entry - how many is typically not relevant.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, I totally agree with you. Thanks to bring this out.